# Result of parallizing for loop with OpenMP varies just slightly from sequential run

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a for loop for a simple ray tracing program using OpenMP. It all seems to work fine, and the generated file seems to be almost identical to the sequential output put there is always one slight tiny difference in the files generated, and the difference is almost always in the same place.

The for loop i am trying to parallelize is this for loop which I did like so:

```
// Parallelize the inner loop
    #pragma omp parallel for private(x, pixel, xx, yy, raydir, ncalls) reduction(+:ncalls_line)
    for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
      pixel = &image[y * width + x];
      xx = (2 * ((x + 0.5) * invWidth) - 1) * angle * aspectratio;
      yy = (1 - 2 * ((y + 0.5) * invHeight)) * angle;
      Vec3_new(&raydir, xx, yy, -1);
      Vec3_normalize(&raydir);
      ncalls = trace(pixel, &origin, &raydir, size, spheres, 0);
      ncalls_line += ncalls;
    }  // End of parallel loop`
```

I generated two files, one is generating the file sequentially, one with the parallelized for loop. When comparing the two files using the cmp command in linux, there always seems to be a difference in the binary file at byte 17 line 4.
I also tried, instead of doing a reduction for ncalls_line, using the directive #omp_critical on it which also did not work and the difference seems to be at the exact same byte. Does anyone know a way to fix this issue?

This is the full source code for the function

```
void render(const unsigned size, const Sphere spheres[size])
{
  //sequential start time
  double start = omp_get_wtime();

  //  unsigned width = 640, height = 480;
  unsigned width = 1024, height = 768;
  Vec3 *image, *pixel, origin, raydir;
  Real invWidth = 1 / (Real)width, invHeight = 1 / (Real)height;
  Real fov = 30, aspectratio = width / (Real)height;
  Real xx, yy, angle = tan(M_PI * 0.5 * fov / 180.0);
  unsigned x, y, i;
  int ncalls;
  double ncalls_line, max_ncalls_line, min_ncalls_line;
  int histo[HIST_N_INTV];
  FILE *F;

  image = malloc(width * height * sizeof(*image));
  Vec3_new0(&origin);
  init_histogram(histo);
  max_ncalls_line = 0;
  min_ncalls_line = INFINITY;

  // Trace rays
  for (y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    ncalls_line = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
      pixel = &image[y*width+x];
      xx = (2 * ((x + 0.5) * invWidth) - 1) * angle * aspectratio;
      yy = (1 - 2 * ((y + 0.5) * invHeight)) * angle;
      Vec3_new(&raydir, xx, yy, -1);
      Vec3_normalize(&raydir);
      ncalls = trace(pixel, &origin, &raydir, size, spheres, 0);
      ncalls_line += ncalls;
    }
    ncalls_line = ncalls_line/width;
    if (ncalls_line < min_ncalls_line)
      min_ncalls_line = ncalls_line;
    if (ncalls_line > max_ncalls_line)
      max_ncalls_line = ncalls_line;
    update_histogram(histo, ncalls_line);
  }

  //ending time before writing to console and to file
  double end = omp_get_wtime();
  double execTime = end - start;
  printf("Sequential execution time: %f", execTime);

  print_histogram(histo);
  printf("Least complex line had %6.3f calls to trace per pixel.\n", min_ncalls_line);
  printf("Most  complex line had %6.3f calls to trace per pixel.\n", max_ncalls_line);

  // Save result to a PPM image (keep these flags if you compile under Windows)
  F = fopen("./sequential.ppm", "wb");
  fprintf(F, "P6\n%u %u\n255\n", width, height);
  for (i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) {
    fprintf(F, "%c%c%c",
        (unsigned char)(min(1.0, image[i].x) * 255),
        (unsigned char)(min(1.0, image[i].y) * 255),
        (unsigned char)(min(1.0, image[i].z) * 255));
  }
  fclose(F);
  free(image);
}
```

Comment: Declare all local variables such as `xx,yy` local to the loop. Then 1. you don't have to make them private and 2. we don't have to think so hard about whether they may cause a problem. Also declare all loop variable local: `for (int i=whatever`. That will prevent trouble in your `for (x ...... for (y` loop.

Comment: The `trace()` function receives pointers as its second and third arguments.  Is that because it may modify the objects to which those point?  If so, then your loop is probably not parallelizable, because each iteration depends what what modifications the previous ones have made to those objects.  Marking them private (which you have done for `raydir` but not for `origin`) does not resolve that issue.

Comment: More generally, are you sure that the `trace()` function is thread-safe?